# Notepad++ Deleting everything apart from 40 variables, putting them on their own line, combining regex

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I am in Notepad++. I have the following data embedded in a large html file. I want to get the variables before the `</ix:nonNumeric>` at the end of the lines, onto their own lines by themselves so the output is:

`00891906 
1.12.13
30.11.14
30.11.14
Company Accounts
Private Limited Company`

etc.

There is more data but if I can get regex to do this, I will be able to work the rest out. Thanks. Once working, I will use the Batch Replace in a directory and do this to a number of txt files.

```
            `<ix:hidden>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_30_11_2014" name="ns7:NameAuthor" order="1" tupleRef="XBRLDocumentAuthorGrouping_Group45" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL"></ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_30_11_2014" name="ns7:DescriptionOrTitleAuthor" order="2" tupleRef="XBRLDocumentAuthorGrouping_Group45" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL"></ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_30_11_2014" name="ns7:UKCompaniesHouseRegisteredNumber" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">00891906</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="CountriesHypercube_FY_30_11_2014_Set1" name="ns7:CountryFormationOrIncorporation" format="ixt2:nocontent" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL" />
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="CurrenciesHypercube_FY_30_11_2014_Set2" name="ns7:PrincipalCurrencyUsedInBusinessReport" format="ixt2:nocontent" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL" />
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="EntityOfficersHypercube_FY_30_11_2014_Set3" name="ns5:NameDirectorSigningAccounts" format="ixt2:nocontent" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL" />
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="cfwd_30_11_2014" name="ns7:StartDateForPeriodCoveredByReport" format="ixt2:datedaymonthyear" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">1.12.13</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="cfwd_30_11_2014" name="ns7:EndDateForPeriodCoveredByReport" format="ixt2:datedaymonthyear" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">30.11.14</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="cfwd_30_11_2014" name="ns7:BalanceSheetDate" format="ixt2:datedaymonthyear" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">30.11.14</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_30_11_2014" name="ns7:EntityAccountsType" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">Company accounts</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_30_11_2014" name="ns7:LegalFormOfEntity" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">Private Limited Company</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_30_11_2014" name="ns7:DescriptionPeriodCoveredByReport" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">FY</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_30_11_2014" name="ns7:EntityTrading" format="ixt2:booleantrue" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">true</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_30_11_2014" name="ns7:EntityDormant" format="ixt2:booleanfalse" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">false</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_30_11_2014" name="ns5:AccountsPreparedUnderHistoricalCostConventionInAccordanceWithFRSSE" format="ixt2:booleantrue" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">true</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_30_11_2014" name="ns5:CompanyExemptFromPreparingCashFlowStatementUnderFRS1" format="ixt2:booleanfalse" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">false</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_30_11_2014" name="ns5:AccountsHaveBeenPreparedInAccordanceWithProvisionsSmallCompaniesRegime" format="ixt2:booleantrue" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">true</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_30_11_2014" name="ns5:RelatedPartyTransactionExemptionBeingClaimed" format="ixt2:booleanfalse" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">false</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_30_11_2014" name="ns6:CompanyHasActedAsAnAgentDuringPeriod" format="ixt2:booleanfalse" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">false</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="SharesHypercube_FY_30_11_2014_Set4" name="ns7:DescriptionShareType" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">Ordinary</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonFraction contextRef="SharesHypercube_FY_30_11_2014_Set4" name="ns5:ParValueShare" unitRef="GBP" decimals="INF" format="ixt2:numdotdecimal" scale="0" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">1.00000</ix:nonFraction>
            <ix:tuple name="ns7:XBRLDocumentAuthorGrouping" tupleID="XBRLDocumentAuthorGrouping_Group45" /></ix:hidden>
            <ix:references>
            <link:schemaRef xlink:href="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/gaap/core/2009-09-01/uk-gaap-full-2009-09-01.xsd" xlink:type="simple" /></ix:references>
            <ix:resources>
            <xbrli:unit id="GBP"><xbrli:measure>iso4217:GBP</xbrli:measure></xbrli:unit><xbrli:unit id="USD"><xbrli:measure>iso4217:USD</xbrli:measure>`
```

Comment: does the random contain any < and > chars too?

Comment: Are all of your variables preceded by digitdigitdigit>? And does that pattern appear elsewhere? If the answers are "yes" and "no" then simply search for that 4 character prefix and for < as the terminator. Sorry not trying to build regexes on a mobile device.

Comment: @LPChip Yeah, it contains : . > < ? $ ... allsorts. I don't think that matters as the expression works for ONE variable. But I need to combine the expressions to start again at the end of the first Variable found, and repeat for the next variable. Not certain on the boolean format to combine.

Comment: It does matter, because if it wouldn't you could simply search for < anything > variable < anything >. But that is not the case now, making things a lot more complicated, as you'll have to start using the | operator (OR) and use a list.

Comment: Or perhaps you should use 40 different regexes, one for each variable, and use multiple (...) patterns, refering to \1 \2 \3 accordingly.

Comment: @fencepost varibles are preceeded by random data. Which doesn't matter because I can put the random data directly behind the variable, into the expression and it picks it out fine. I don't mind writing a new expression for each variable I am doing, that's fine, as long as I can combine them.

Comment: @LPChip Yeah, I want to do that but don't know how to do it. I can write the 40 different ones no problem, and get it working, but only individually. Can't work out how to "combine" them and get each Variable on a seperate line. Do I need to put the 40 variables together in the Find box?

Comment: @LPChip @fencepost I should be able to do it in one line... `delete everything before "expression" delete everything after that but only up to "2nd expression",*INSERT LINE BREAK* delete everything after that but only up to "3rd expression" *INSERT LINE BREAK* delete after that but only up to "4th expression" *INSERT LINE BREAK*... "40th expression" *delete everything up to end of doc*`... any ideas on the code for that?

Comment: Hi @LPChip, do you know how to combine the 40 regexes I have written? when I put them all together in the find&replace box it doesn't work. I need it all doing in "one" go.

Comment: I'm sorry. My regex is not fluently either. I'd need to have the entire code and use trial and error to get it working at some point. Your question is just too complex to write you a simple answer or I would've.

Comment: @LPChip if you can please solve the example data at the top of this into its 3 variables with nothing else, and post code, I will be able to work out how to adapt it...thanks?

Comment: @LPChip @fencepost I've also noticed that this works:  `.* <expression with (.+?)> .*` but again can't work out how to combine them. I just cant work out what term needs to go inbetween the expressions. I know it's `.*` at the very start and very end but dont know what symbol to put in the middle - ie `delete everything going forwards, but only up to <expression start>` do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example you gave, the following regex will work:

Find what:
`.+?(<.+?>)(.+?)(<.+?>)`

Replace with:
`\2\r`

This will give the following result with your data:

```
VARIABLE 1
VARIABLE 2
VARIABLE 3
 randomrandom random randomrandom random randomrandom  random random randomrandom random randomrandom random
```

Only the last line will not be filtered out, but that can be manually removed.

Comment: I tried that with two variables and it does give 3 lines, the first variable it on the top line, great, but the next two lines are blank! I am replacing the `<.+?>` with my expression yes? And leaving the `(.+?)` in the middle of my two expressions yes? (my expression contains a `(.+?)` to get the variable out of the expression)...

Comment: This is driving me mad I wish I could send you a text file showing my data and show you the actual expressions and variables that I want out of it.

Comment: No, you use the code provided as is. It should do it. I tested it with the example you gave and that was my output. Basically it searches for text, then the first <, then some more text, then the > and what comes then between that and the next < is your variable.

Comment: Just a moment...

Comment: I can't get this to work with my data. I am trying to find a site I can upload the text and data (~130k) to to show you...

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/jaderaw

Comment: Uploaded jaderaw.txt - if there is a better site to upload to please let me know, or an email. Many thanks.

Comment: I plugged my expressions from my data (not the example data) into `.+?(<.+?>)(.+?)(<.+?>)` and it does return 3 lines, but only the first variable shows, the next two lines are blank.

Comment: I've managed to condense the data I will edit the original post and show you exactly what I'm trying to do. Two seconds

Comment: Done. See original post above and please write regex to attain output explained.

Comment: I've worked out a workaround at the moment. I am having to do it in bulk replace using one regex at a time. Thanks.